# Is there an easy way to add some prefix to all model names in some Openapi spec?

Tags: swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I need some automated way to modify schemas' names in the openapi spec, adding some prefix there (some java lib or maven plugin would be preferable, but any hint on how to do it properly is also welcome). The input is an openapi yaml file and the output should be an adjusted openapi yaml file. Modifying the generated java models is not an option as I need an adjusted spec file itself, to share it further. For example, if the original file looks like this (please note that some models are also referenced within the `discriminator`'s `mapping`):

```yaml
openapi: "3.0.1"
info:
  title: "Pet clinic"
  version: "1.0"
paths:
  /pets/{petId}:
    get:
      summary: Info for a specific pet
      operationId: showPetById
      tags:
        - pets
      parameters:
        - name: petId
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The id of the pet to retrieve
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Expected response to a valid request
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Pet"
        default:
          description: unexpected error
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Error"
components:
  schemas:
    Pet:
      type: object
      required:
        - id
        - name
        - some_complex_field
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        name:
          type: string
        tag:
          type: string
        some_complex_field:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/ObjectWithInheritance"
    Pets:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: "#/components/schemas/Pet"
    Error:
      type: object
      required:
        - code
        - message
      properties:
        code:
          type: integer
          format: int32
        message:
          type: string
    ObjectWithInheritance:
      type: object
      properties:
        objectType:
          type: string
      required:
        - objectType
      discriminator:
        propertyName: objectType
        mapping:
          Cash: Cash
          Internal: Internal
    Cash:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/ObjectWithInheritance'
        - type: object
          properties:
            currencyCode:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/CurrencyCode'
          required:
            - currencyCode
    CurrencyCode:
      type: string
    Internal:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/ObjectWithInheritance'
        - type: object
          properties:
            identifier:
              type: string
          required:
            - identifier
```

The adjusted file should like like this (note that all components got the "Prefixed" word in their names):

```yaml
openapi: "3.0.1"
info:
  title: "Pet clinic"
  version: "1.0"
paths:
  /pets/{petId}:
    get:
      summary: Info for a specific pet
      operationId: showPetById
      tags:
        - pets
      parameters:
        - name: petId
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The id of the pet to retrieve
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Expected response to a valid request
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/PrefixedPet"
        default:
          description: unexpected error
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/PrefixedError"
components:
  schemas:
    PrefixedPet:
      type: object
      required:
        - id
        - name
        - some_complex_field
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        name:
          type: string
        tag:
          type: string
        some_complex_field:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/PrefixedObjectWithInheritance"
    PrefixedPets:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: "#/components/schemas/PrefixedPet"
    PrefixedError:
      type: object
      required:
        - code
        - message
      properties:
        code:
          type: integer
          format: int32
        message:
          type: string
    PrefixedObjectWithInheritance:
      type: object
      properties:
        objectType:
          type: string
      required:
        - objectType
      discriminator:
        propertyName: objectType
        mapping:
          Cash: PrefixedCash
          Internal: PrefixedInternal
    PrefixedCash:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/PrefixedObjectWithInheritance'
        - type: object
          properties:
            currencyCode:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/PrefixedCurrencyCode'
          required:
            - currencyCode
    PrefixedCurrencyCode:
      type: string
    PrefixedInternal:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/PrefixedObjectWithInheritance'
        - type: object
          properties:
            identifier:
              type: string
          required:
            - identifier
```

Comment: None that I'm aware of. To do a similar thing we had to write a script to do search/replace. You can handle the file as a text file or use a YAML parser or [OpenAPI parser](https://openapi.tools/#parsers).

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doing the same eventually.